# Rotate array and store all combination in object variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have month array which should be rotate **left** to **right** for its length time. Store all rotational array in object variable. Can you please suggest more efficient way to do it.

```
var Month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];


 Output looks like:

 monthRotate = {
                      rotate1: ["Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan"],
                      rotate2: ["Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb"],
                       .
                       .
                       . 
                       .
                      rotate11: ["Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"]; 
             }
```

I have tried this below method.

```js
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var rotate = {};
for (var i=1;i<months.length;i++){
 var mts = months.slice(i).concat(months.slice(0,i));
 rotate["rotate"+i] = mts;
}

console.log(rotate);
```

Comment: more efficient than what? for loop would be the most efficient, but even more efficient is to not rotate at all but just use something like `Month[(index + rotate) % 12]`

Comment: You should make a clever use of the `Array.shift`and `Array.unshift` prototypes, likely linked through `Array.concat`. Please show your effort though, I don't see much there but the output.

Comment: I'm thinking a Recursive method would be an alternative

Comment: The code looks good. And btw a recursive method is not always fast. It requires call stack and in some cases stack overflow occurs, thus you shouldn't feel like a recursive algo will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift` method in order to remove the first element of the given `array` and then **push** it at the end of the **array.**

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
let final = [...Array(months.length-1)].reduce(function(arr){
   months.push(months.shift());
   arr.push([...months]);
   return arr;
},[]);
console.log(final);
```

Comment: Interesting approach using .reduce and ES6. Also, clever idea to use the spread operator to avoid reference issues, well done!

Comment: Thanks Alexandar! This code look like more efficient way to get my output.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `rotations` array object in this way:

```
var Month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var rotations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    rotations[i] = [];
   for(var j = i+1, k = 0; k < 12; j++, k++){
      if(j === 12){
         j = 0;
      } 
      rotations[i].push(month[j]);
   }
}
```

Console output:
[image]